# Exclude ambiguous columns in SELECT statement (actually CREATE VIEW statement)

Tags: sql, view, duplicates

After reading around, I've realized that SQL (*MySQL in my case*) does not support column exclusion.

```
SELECT *, NOT excluded_column FROM table; /* shame it doesn't work */
```

Anyways, while I've come to accept that, I'm wondering if there's any decent workarounds to achieve this sort of behavior. Reason being, I'm creating a **view** to consolidate information across a few tables.

I've normalized some user data to tables `user` and `user_profile` among others; purpose being that `user` stores data critical to user operations, and `user_profile` stores non-critical data. Application requirements are still being realized, so columns are being added/removed from `user_profile` as necessary, and further tables may be supported down the line which would be included in the view.

Problem is, when I create the view, I get `Error 1060: Duplicate Column Name` because `user_id` is present in both tables.

Now, the solution I've come up with so far, is basically:

```
/* exclude user_id from user */
SELECT user.critical_field, user.other_critical_field,
       user_profile.*
FROM user
LEFT JOIN user_profile
ON user.user_id = user_profile.user_id;
```

Since the `user` table is going to remain unchanged throughout the application lifecycle (*hopefully*) this could suffice, but I was just curious if a more dynamic approach exists.

(*Table names were not copypasta'd, I know `user` is often a poor choice of naming convention on it's own, I use prefixes.*)

Comment: Inexplicable *-1*'s are unhelpful. If my question is unclear, or suggests a poor choice, I'd like to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, I'll define which fields I want to be in my view

Using your example:

```
SELECT user.critical_field, user.other_critical_field,
       user_profile.User_Id, user_profile.MyOtherOfield
FROM user
LEFT JOIN user_profile
ON user.user_id = user_profile.user_id;
```

Now, additionally, I'll make sure that I alias things properly:

```
SELECT u.critical_field, u.other_critical_field,
           up.User_Id, up.MyOtherOfield, u.KeyField AS userKey, up.KeyField as ProfileKey
    FROM user as u
    LEFT JOIN user_profile as up
    ON u.user_id = up.user_id;
```

This allows me to ensure I know what's in my view, and that the columns are named intelligently, but it does mean that I'll need to touch that view when I make changes to the underlying table structures.

Comment: Thanks **Stephen Wrighton**; I figured that would be the case. I don't have an issue with synchronizing my view when the tables change, but I presume there exists no alternative. I also presume my current solution is sub-optimal.

Comment: I've seen no other alternatives, but at the same time I've not looked. Mainly because I like this way of doing things, as I like the control.

Comment: Sounds good. I believe this will be my choice. I was hoping for a dynamic alternative mainly for development purposes, moving to a column specific view definition for deployment. I may as well do it "right" the first time.